# XmlElement required = true for Integer doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-rs, required

I use jax-rs service. I have two fields in my class annotated with @XmlElement(required = true), one for Boolean, another for Integer. but if I send xml tags without value, for boolean I receive null, but for Integer I receive 0

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
private Integer intValue;

@XmlElement(required = true)
private Boolean booleanValue;
```

why I'm not receive null in Integer?

Comment: Check that getter and setter also use Integer and not int

Comment: It's ok both with setter and getter. It's strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just should added defaultValue = "null"

```
@XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "null")
private Integer intValue;
```

There are 'interesting' (not expected) behavior of Integer fields. I can not find an explanation for what values ​​are assigned to the default Integers in jaxb.

Answer (score 1):

The `required` property on the `@XmlElement` annotation has no impact on the marshalling/unmarshalling performed by JAXB.  It simply used during XML Schema generation to determine if the element declaration should have a `minOccurs` of `0` (for false), or `1` (for true).

The difference between unmarshalling behaviour for `Boolean` and `Integer` is due to a bug in the JAXB reference implementation.