# XML unmarshalling of Interger type data in jax-rs

Tags: jaxb, jax-rs, unmarshalling

We have a peculiar issue where empty xml tags are getting unmarshalled to 0 (Zero). this is causing problem during data insertion into db and retrieval.

eg. 
for the xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <afBoundData>  
        <intData1/>
        <intData2/>0</intData2>
    </afBoundData>
```

The corresponding class is

```
class AfBoundData {
      Integer intData1;
      Integer intData2;
}
```

After unmarshalling the XML into the class both intData1 and intData2 are having values as 0 (Zero)

but we were expecting null in intData1 and 0 in intData2.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the default value for your `Integer` fields by using the `@XmlElement` annotation:

```
class AfBoundData {
    @XmlElement(defaultValue = "null")
    Integer intData1;

    @XmlElement(defaultValue = "null")
    Integer intData2;
}
```

By the way, your question is very similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527655/xmlelement-required-true-for-integer-doesnt-work).

Comment: Cool, now the problem is AfBoundData is generated using a huge XSD. which does not have default value set. Can you suggest if I can use binding  here to generate the annotations

Comment: @Ravi Ask a new question and reference this one.  You will get a good answer.